# Fazer tópico com publicação mais recente aparecer no topo em sistema de fórum

Tags: php

Tenho uma dúvida de um fórum que estou criando do zero.
Tenho a listagem dos tópicos do fórum. Quando uma pessoa comenta em tal tópico este tópico deveria subir na listagem (ficar em primeiro). Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando fizer os select nos tópicos ordene pelo ultimo id

```
SELECT * FROM `teste` ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta mas pelo que entendi é isso ou é o caminho para a sua duvida!

Comment: Vlw! Era isso mesmo, só que criei um timestamp na tabela dos tópicos, a cada comentário lá faz um UPDATE e ele será exibido conforme o horário!